# Nltk in xls files

Tags: python, xml, nlp, nltk

There is no problem accessing the file but while reading I get the following error

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordListCorpusReader
reader= WordListCorpusReader("C:\\Users\samet\\nltk_data\\corpora\\bilgi\samet",
["politika.xls"])

a = reader.words()
print (a)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q0HS.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to make sure the file you're trying to load (politika.xls) is saved with utf-8 encoding.  First I'll detail how I replicated your error, then I'll show an approach to solve it.

I was able to replicate your error as follows:

1. Create a new text document.  "temp.txt"
2. Open it, add a few lines random text, save and close it.
3. Rename "temp.txt" to "temp.xls"
4. Open "temp.xls"
5. Save as.... "temp.xlsx"
6. Close file.
7. Rename "temp.xlsm" to "politika.xls"
8. Try running your code (with correction to path).
9. Receive your error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte"

There may be a more straightforward approach, but from the above error condition, this worked to fix it:

1. Create a backup copy of "politika.xls"
2. Rename "politika.xls" to "old_politika.xls"
3. Create a new text file "politika.txt".
   #Steps 3.1 - 3.4 may or may not be needed.
   3.1. Open "politika.txt"
   3.2. Save as...
   3.3. Select Encoding >> (either ANSI or UTF-8 should work)
   3.4. Save and close file.
4. Rename "politika.txt" to "politika.csv"
5. Open up "old_politika.xls"
6. Select and copy the data.
7. Open up "politika.csv"
8. Paste the data.  Save and exit.
9. Rename "politika.csv" to "politika.xls"
10. Run your program. (See below for code / potential correction)

Also, you'll want to fix your directory path.  Make sure you use the excape character "\" for each "\" in the path.  You were missing a "\" in front of " \samet" in 2 places.  Corrected code below:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import WordListCorpusReader
reader= WordListCorpusReader("C:\\Users\\samet\\nltk_data\\corpora\\bilgi\\samet",
["politika.xls"])

a = reader.words()
print (a)
```

I hope this helps.